Has there ever been a transfer of occupants from one aircraft to another while airborne?
Similar to the mechanism used in aircraft tankers (picture below), has there ever been a transfer of occupants from one aircraft to another using some sort of "air bridge"?

Crazy idea: How cool it would be if you could make a connection from a flight to another while airborne. Imagine all the benefits for both airlines and passengers(time saved, airport fees, etc)
I think it would need to be something that when connected would make both aircraft a "single aircraft"(picture below) (to avoid stuff like turbulence), yet a the same time very easy/safe to couple and decouple.

NASA's 747 carrying Space Shuttle. June 2, 2009

Harrison Ford as the US President vibes increasing! get off my plane!!

Barnstormers are reported to have done this.

Anything goes wrong while you're in the middle of that "bridge", you are dead-er than dead! Thanks, but I'd rather connect in Atlanta.

"Imagine all the benefits for both airlines and passengers" yep, especially the two airplane crashing into each other and some passenger missing the bridge and flying away without parachute... WAIT, YOU FORGOT YOUR TROLLEY!!!

ohh come one don't be that cruel....and I bet the FAA certification process would be super easy and quick

Pretty sure the Shuttle wasn't intended to mate up in flight (with the glider having to join up on the jet -- added degree of difficulty there).  Nor any tunnel to connect the two through the orbiter's heat shield.

@RalphJ I really just meant something like it, I know it wasn't intended for that lol. But yeah, I admit it, the idea is just too crazy, I was just passing trough a moment of excitement about this idea. My common senses and reasoning were gone.

see the film Executive Decision :-)

@AaronF indeed, I totally forgot that film.

these folks are prepping it ~ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh06wlg9RmU

Pretty sure Redbull have moved people from plane to plane - but more likely using those flying squirrel suits than something as sedate and sane sounding (ha!) as a "bridge".

Oh wow. I tried to imagine all the benefits, and came up with none. Disadvatages however were plenty.

One of the Airport movies did this.  Pilots are out of it, and the stewardess is in the cockpit.  They try to transfer a pilot or two though the open cockpit.  Think it was 50/50.

I must admit, I had no idea if the "wire thing" in the Air Force One movie was completely fictional, or perhaps some idea that "special forces" or whatever were actually trying out, or perhaps the air force had experimented with or such. I guess then, it was a totally fictional "Boy's Own" idea. Perhaps someone here knows for sure!

Of course there has! No air bridge involved, however.

This picture shows one of several such performances made for movies or at airshows in the 1920s. The earliest I could find was done by Jim Hester in 1920 for the movie Go Get It.
From the Online Archives of California:

James Harvey Hester was a Stunt Flyer who was associated with the famous Hollywood Black Cats. He served in the USAAS at Kelly Field, TX briefly during WWI then returned to Venice. He was a test and stunt pilot in the southern California area between 1919 and 1925

Follow the link to the San Diego Air & Space Museum collection for more, and treasures like these:



The 13 Black Cats charged one hundred dollars for an ordinary plane-change. It cost five hundred dollars to make a change made from an upside-down aircraft to one flying right side up. A crowd thrilling addition was a faked accident with the apparent victim falling off the aircraft and tumbling about four hundred feet before a thin cable (invisible to the audience) suddenly opened a hidden parachute, to the gasped relief of the audience.


Ahhh... the days before OSHA and Health and Safety.

X-1 pilots took off in the mothership B-29 and transferred to the rocket plane in the air.

At 12,000 feet Yeager, with Ridley behind him, crawled through the hatch to the unpressurized bomb bay. The air temperature was well below zero, and the airstream howled in the confined space. Clad only in a flight suit and leather jacket, Yeager stepped onto the ladder fitted to the right side of the bomb bay, then wormed his way into the X-1’s hatch outside the B-29. Ridley remained on the ladder as the X-1 door was lowered by another crewman. He helped Yeager fit it into place.

https://www.historynet.com/bell-x-1-dropping-the-orange-beast/
An addition to show the ingress setup:
This shows the X-1 tucked under the B-29. The combo was launched hatch-off. You can see the big square hole in the side of the X-1.

This is looking forward and up into the bomb bay with the X-1 not present. The highlighted structure is the retractable ladder. Note it is closed in on three sides and has a floor, the X-1 outer mold line would close off the remaining side when the ladder was extended.

Here's a pilot (Goodlin) transferring from the B-29 to the X-1. The ladder is behind him and the X-1 canopy is visible in front of him.

All photos from Bell X-1 Variants by Guenther and Miller.

I came here to say this. You've already said it, 13 hours ago :-) .

This now sounds like one of the most interesting parts of the X-1 test and even from the article I don't fully understand how they did it.  It sounds like they had two people hanging on a ladder below a flying B-29 who remove, hope not to drop, and then reinstall a door plug in the X-1--and one of those people had broken ribs and went on to fly it.

@ErinAnne I'm flipping through the Aerofax Bell X-1 book and they don't have a great diagram or picture of the ingress setup. But yeah, you described it pretty well. The retractable ladder had a kind of box around three sides of it and a floor, so they weren't totally out in the breeze. I'll add in the best pictures I could find.

amazing. I probably should've asked that as its own question, but the X-1 ladder is now one of the best interface adapters I've seen in my life.

The Red Bull plane swap counts - jumping from one plane to another whilst in free-fall. One person was successful, the other plane went out of control and crashed. The FAA wasn't happy about it...

Well over 20 years ago there was an IMAX movie called "Flyers" that featured a mid-air rescue of a fallen wing walker who had no parachute, but I can't remember whether the rescue plane was the one he/she fell off of (which obviously wouldn't count), or a different one!  Clarification-- this was a fictional story.  What mid-air transfers had to actually be perfomed to get the footage of interest, I have no idea.

Fascinating.  Re the linked video-- they got at least one thing wrong, those were obviously not single-seat planes.

This successful Red Bull stunt would have also counted if the wingsuit flyers had started from a second plane rather than BASE jumping from a mountain into a plane. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL9sNrOlK-I

Mentour AKA Petter covered it (on the "Mentour Now!" channel). Published 2022-05-05. It was about the same time as the Trevor Jacob stunt (within a few months).

What came to mind was a few military projects, although this list is not exhaustive.  Unfortunately the "easy/safe to couple and decouple" was generally a problem. Also note that you not only have to transfer the passenger, but also their baggage.
In the 1930's there were the airships USS Akron and USS Macon which were capable of carrying, launching, and recovering fighters while in the air.
All pictures are from Wikipedia.


The second is the XF-85 Goblin (Note: The plan was to hook up to a B-36, but testing was done with a modified B-29). From Wikipedia:

Two main reasons contributed to the cancellation. The XF-85's deficiencies revealed in flight testing included a lackluster performance in relation to contemporary jet fighters, and the high demands on pilot skill experienced during docking revealed a critical shortcoming that was never fully corrected.


The third one is the related FICON project using a B-36 and F-84. The pilot was able to leave the F-84 while attached to the B-36, but again connecting proved difficult (again quoting Wikipedia):

Subsequent test flights demonstrated the FICON concept was indeed "tactically sound", but its operational implementation was difficult. A total of 10 GRB-36Ds and 25 RF-84Ks were built and saw limited service in 1955–56. Hookups with the carrier aircraft were challenging for the experienced test pilots under ideal conditions. In combat or in adverse weather, and by less-experienced pilots, they proved difficult, and several RF-84Ks were damaged attempting it.



{ Poorly sourced info FYI: }
https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1024005
This bloke claims it has been done a couple times,
"There have been a few aircraft to aircraft transfers done in the real world..."
And following the links other blokes claim it was actually done for real (not effects), with a rope in the Cliffhanger movie.
Other reports claim that he did not actually complete the transfer, while filming.
Unfortunately you can google numerous conflicting stories about that stunt.
